# A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter?

Tags: c#, properties, member, indexer, grasshopper

In the code below, I get the error

> A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter?

on the `m_settings.Length`argument when compiling it. How could I solve this?

```
  public override bool Read(GH_IO.Serialization.GH_IReader reader)
                {
                    if (m_settings != null && m_settings.Length > 0)
                    {
                        reader.TryGetInt32("StringCount", ref m_settings.Length);
                        for (int i = 0; i < m_settings.Length; i++)
                        {
                            reader.TryGetString("String", i, ref m_settings[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return base.Read(reader);
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I solve this?

By not doing that :) How would you expect it to work anyway? Assuming `m_settings` is an array, an array can't change length anyway...

If you *really* need `ref` behaviour, you'll need a local variable:

```
int length = m_settings.Length;
reader.TryGetInt32("StringCount", ref length);

// Presumably you want to use length here...
// Perhaps m_settings = new string[length];  ?
```

It's frankly a little odd that:

- `TryGetInt32` uses a `ref` parameter instead of an `out` parameter, unlike the normal `TryXXX` pattern
- You're ignoring the return value of `TryGetInt32`, which I'd expect to be a success/failure value. Why would you want to silently ignore failure?

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary local variable:

```
int temp = 0;
if (reader.TryGetInt32("StringCount", ref temp)) {
    m_settings.Length = temp;
}
```

Of course this still leaves open some questions:

- you don't check the return value of `TryGetInt32` -- what if the conversion fails?
- is `m.settings.Length` really writeable?